# Swift Merging Audio Files causes "Consider using asynchronous alternative function"

Tags: ios, swift, audio, merge

I am simply trying to merge an array of audio files. Every stack overflow thread for this is outdated and doesn't work. I get the warning "Consider using asynchronous alternative function" on **exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {**. Im not sure why this happens. I'd appreciate the help.

```
    func mergeAudios(recordings: [Recording], completion: @escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession) -> ()) async {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
        
        guard let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else { return }
        
        for recording in recordings {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: recording.fileURL)
            
            do {
                try await audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.load(.duration)), of: asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            do {
                lastTime = try await CMTimeAdd(lastTime, asset.load(.duration))
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: Temp Output URL
        let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "MergedAudio-\(Date()).mp3")
        
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
        exportSession?.outputFileType = .m4a
        exportSession?.outputURL = tempURL
        
        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {
            completion(exportSession!)
        }
    }
public struct Recording: Hashable {
    public let uid: UUID
    public var fileURL: URL
    
    public init(fileURL: URL) {
        uid = UUID()
        self.fileURL = fileURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for that function?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it be useful to post my answer since I was not able to find an update to date solution. Most SO threads for this are pre 2020.

```
func mergeAudios() async {
    if self.recordings.count > 1 {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
        
        guard let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else { return }
        
        for recording in self.recordings {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: recording.fileURL)
            
            do {
                try await audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.load(.duration)), of: asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
            } catch {
                print("Error inserting time range: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            do {
                lastTime = try await CMTimeAdd(lastTime, asset.load(.duration))
            } catch {
                print("Error adding time: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    
        let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "MergedAudio-\(UUID().uuidString).m4a")
        print("Exporting to: \(tempURL)")
        
        do {
            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
            exporter?.outputURL = tempURL
            
            await exporter?.export()

            let exportedAsset = AVURLAsset(url: tempURL)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.recordings = [Recording(fileURL: tempURL)]
                UserDefaults.standard.set(tempURL.absoluteString, forKey: "tempUrl")
            }
        }
    }
}
public struct Recording: Hashable {
    public let uid: UUID
    public var fileURL: URL
    
    public init(fileURL: URL) {
        uid = UUID()
        self.fileURL = fileURL
    }
}
```